# Using After in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sleep

I have an issue with using .after in tkinter, time.sleep wasn't working either..  What I want is that it shows a WORD for 5 seconds, the word clears and an entry appears. It was working fine without using .after, but now it just get stuck for 5 seconds and the random WORD appears at the some time as the Entry.

I haven't figured out the clearing of the word yet either :-) I'm totally new to programming and python, any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

```
for widget in window.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
WORD = random.choice(VOCABULARY)
tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label (window, text = "{}".format(WORD), bg="black", fg="white", font="none 20 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0)
window.after(5000)
ANSWER = tk.Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
ANSWER.grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Button(window, text="Check", width=6, command=check) .grid(row=3, column=0)
WORDS_PASSED.append("{}".format(WORD))
VOCABULARY.remove("{}".format(WORD))
```

Comment: Simple fix is to add `window.update()` before `window.after(5000)`.  To remove the WORD, you need to separate the line `tk.Label (window, text = "{}".format(WORD),...).grid(...)` into 2 lines: `word = tk.Label(...)` and `word.grid(...)`.  Then use `word.grid_forget()` after `window.after(5000)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for helping me again! The window.after is working fine now, but the I think word.grid.forget() literally makes the WORD forget. I need that variable to check if the entry=WORD edit: I also can't append or remove WORD to/from the lists. Now I actually put a new label on the same row with blank spaces and added windows.update(). Bit of a noob solution :-) Also: how is word = tk.Label(...) working since we already said WORD = random(....) also, WORD = tk.Label(..) also contains "text = "{}".format(WORD)" isn't that like self referencing or something?

Comment: I used `word` (small letter) as the variable, not `WORD`.

Comment: @acw1668 ah ok.. that works :-) Can you answer the question? Just out of curiosity: Why is the entry box now moving up to row 1 by itself? And how can I prevent that from happening? It looks a bit cleaner that way.

Comment: If there is no items in a row, that row will be treated as not exist and its height is zero.  So if you want to keep the row, use `word['text'] = ''` instead of `word.grid_forget()`.

Comment: @acw1668 got it! I want to label your answer. Can you answer the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix is to add `window.update()` before `window.after(5000)` to force tkinter to update.  To remove the WORD, you need to separate the line

```
tk.Label (window, text = "{}".format(WORD), bg="black", fg="white", font="none 20 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0)
```

into two line:

```
word = tk.Label(window, text=WORD, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 20 bold")
word.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Then you can use `word['text'] = ''` after `window.after(5000)` to hide the WORD.

Below is the modified code:

```
...
word = tk.Label(window, text=WORD, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 20 bold")
word.grid(row=1, column=0)
window.update()  # force tkinter to update
window.after(5000)
word['text'] = ''  # hide the WORD
...
```

Comment: this will still cause the UI to freeze for 5 seconds, which isn't very user-friendly.

Comment: That is why I said `simple fix`.  It is the least changes on the OP code.